# Any tool for finding satellite passes that overlap *two* given locations?

Tags: satellites, software

gpredict is nice. Well, it's OK, to find the next passes for a set of satellites with sufficient elevation for one location.

What I want is something where I can put in two coordinates, and get out the next of a *set* of satellites that will have a simultaneous pass for two locations, so that I can try to make a specific contact, or a specific square contact.

Comment: Are you up for a bit of Python programming? Everything you need is free and available, just takes a bit of putting together....

Comment: If there's no existing tool, yes. What library or similar do you recommend?

Comment: Existing tools will give you a list of sats and times.  For example, gpredict would let you create two configurations, one for each location, and then flip between them to check by hand for overlapping passes.   Having said that, it wouldn't be too difficult to write what you ask for, especially if you can find code that already generates the pass list.  Maybe gpredict would add this feature if you put in a feature request?